# Loading values into a structure pointer inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, structure, function-pointers

So I'm just trying to load some values into a structure and I can't get it to work. I'm new to C and pointers etc is still a little bit confusing, so I'm not really sure why this doesn't work.

```
struct monster_{
  int health;
  int power;
  int x_position;
  int y_position;
 };


void allocate(struct monster_ **a); 
void init_monster(struct monster_ *a);

int main(){

  struct monster_ *m;
  allocate(&m);
  init_monster(m);


  printf("%d", m->health);

  return 0;
}
void allocate(struct monster_ **a){ 

 *a=(void*)malloc(sizeof(struct monster_));


}
void init_monster(struct monster_ *a){

  a->health = 100;
  a->power = 90;
  a->x_position = 25;
  a->y_position = 90;



}
```

So what I want to happen is that m->health by this point should print 100, but it only prints 0.

EDITED: Earlier code was not really what was in my code. Here is what I actually used.

Comment: This should not compile.. Is this the code you're running to print 0?

Comment: It looks like there are some inconsistencies:  (1) is the struct `mons_` or `monster_`?  You need to use the same name (2) Did you want `print` or `printf`?  (3) add a newline `\n` to the end of the format string.  (4) Fix indentation, it's painful to read like this.

Comment: You are right, I only copied out the bits that I thought there were errors in. I changed it and copied most of the code from my c.file now instead.

Comment: I compiled your code and it printed 100 for me -- how are you compiling it?

Comment: http://ideone.com/UCNxQ1

Comment: I'm new, not sure what answer you are looking for but I'm compiling it on linux without any flags just gcc filename.c and then ./a.out

Comment: try putting a \n in your printf: printf("%d\n", m->health);

Comment: That didn't help, not sure why it would, but is the code working for you aswell?

Comment: Is any member in the monster_ struct right?

Comment: For me the code works fine. For indentation, use tabs. Put an '\n' at the end of the print line.

Comment: @felle: Adding a `\n` at the end of the print statement will help if the terminal is overwriting your program's output (for example, the output `"100"` is overwritten by the prompt `"> "`, meaning all you see is `"> 0"`). Try setting `health` to different values, like `1234567890`, and see what it prints out. If you still see only `0`, then something wacky is happening.

Comment: You are missing `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top.  With those lines present, the code should either output `100`, or nothing.  (To prevent the nothing case, change `"%d"` to `"%d\n"`).   If you still have unexpected output, please make sure that the code in your question is *exactly* what you are compiling and running.

Answer (score 1):

You code works as expected on my computer. I suppose what you need is just the following two head files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```